# How-to integrate clang-tidy with CMake (<LANG>_CLANG_TIDY) and MSVC?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, clang, clang-tidy

How can one pass a `clang` flag, e.g. `-fms-compatibility-version` with the [`<LANG>_CLANG_TIDY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html) CMake property? On the CLI this is easy:

```
clang-tidy main.cpp -- -fms-compatibility-version=19.10
```

But with CMake this does not work as expected:

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY="clang-tidy;-checks=-*,readability-*;--;-fms-compatibility-version=19.10"
```

The flag is required to make `clang` work with modern versions of MSVC.

If this is not possible; Is there any other way to integrate CMake+MSVC+clang-tidy (besides creating a custom build target)?

Answer (score 0):

On Visual studio 2017 15.6.3 (make sure to update) here.

I had to put

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy;-format-style='file'")

# CMake is buggy. It gives the -std:c++14 instead of /std:c++14
# set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /std:c++14")
```

In my `CMakeLists.txt`. I Don't know if that is the right way to do it, but I can compile AND detect errors. Seems like a win to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--extra-arg` and `--extra-arg-before` ([docs](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/)).

> --extra-arg=: Additional argument to append to the compiler command line. Can be used several times.
>
> --extra-arg-before=: Additional argument to prepend to the compiler command line. Can be used several times.

This is supported in earlier versions of CMake, but I'm using it to get C++17 support with CMake 3.16 on Windows as well as linux.

```
if (MSVC)
  if(CLANG_TIDY_EXE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy;--extra-arg-before=-std=c++17;${CLANG_TIDY_ARGS}")
  endif()
endif()
```

For me this was by far the hardest part of integrating CMake+MSVC+clang-tidy ([here's](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18731#note_702382) the details I followed).

Answer (score 0):

[CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY in MSVC](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/cmake-cxx-clang-tidy-in-msvc/890) In this topic, `VS_GLOBAL_ClangTidyChecks` properties maybe effective.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html) you linked to actually said it. Currently (ver 3.13.3) it only works with Makefiles and Ninja. It doesn't work with msbuild.

Comment: I never stated that I used a MSBuild CMake generator. I used a MSVC 15.x compiler with the Ninja generator, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @FlorianWolters Never mind my answer then. I assumed it was msbuild since it's default for MSVC.